# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int' despite a return statement

Tags: python, function, typeerror

```
import random

def guess():
  guess = print(input("What is your first guess?"))
  return guess

def target():
  target = random.randint(1, 100)
  return target

def check(guess, target):
  if guess() > target():
    print("Too high")
  elif guess() < target():
    print("Too low")
  else:
    print("You got it!")

check(guess, target)
```

I was wondering why this code outputs an error

> TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'int'

I have looked at other questions and users have recommended returning from both functions, which I have done above.

Comment: Remove print() where you are assigning input to guess. print() returns None type. Second, cast guess to int type.

Comment: As the error states, `guess` is `None` and `target` is an `int`, and there's no logical way to compare those